# Gesture Swipe in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I am working on a app where in i have a basic activity,When i swipe from left to right i need i need to get a swipe window which will display few icons,when i click from right to left i need to get an swipe window from right to left...i researched a bit...nd found few options like navigation drawer and swipe window and view pager....but swipe gesture jst swipes continuously from one page to another...i dont want that...i need to display few icons when i swipe from left to right and right to left....but i don't know exactly which one to use for better navigation....
i used the following code:

@Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            String swipe = "";
            float sensitvity = 50;

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity){
            swipe += "Swipe Left\n";
            SwipeLeft();
        }else if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){
            swipe += "Swipe Right\n";
        }else{
            swipe += "\n";
        }

        if((e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > sensitvity){
            swipe += "Swipe Up\n";
        }else if((e2.getY() - e1.getY()) > sensitvity){
            swipe += "Swipe Down\n";
        }else{
            swipe += "\n";
        }

        gestureEvent.setText(swipe);

        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
};
```

I am confused on wthr i should use swipe of view pager..
this is something what i want..[image]
Help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted try something like navigation drawer from both side of screen i.e. Right to left swap and Left to right following [link will help you](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Comment: Yours WL.

You need to add it as library project in your application, you can get all code from above link, just you need to customize it according to your need.

Comment: yeah i downloaded that application....but its giving me a error unable to resolve target 'android-16'....i tried to change the minimum version in manifest....but its still not working...also can u tell me y do we need to add it as a lib project??...

Comment: [check out this link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: yeah thanks....and one more thing is it possible to make an navigation drawer from both sides....like can i make it one from left and one from right??..

Comment: Navigation Drawer is panel which is android api and above mentioned sliding menu is 3rd party library.....

So I think its not possible to add **navigation drawer** from right to left I don't have much idea about that but yes its possible we can add **sliding menu** from both side of screen.
i.e. left to right and right to left. I have used in one of my project.

Comment: ok...thanks..even i was researching about it...didnt get anything...well is it possible for you to gve me de source code of sliding menu??

Comment: Ya buddy there no problem to give you code, but have you tried to implement example which was given by **Jeremy Feinstein** ??